# Поиск на сайте с другого сайта

Tags: php, html, поиск

Доброе время суток. Как можно организовать на своем сайте поиск по другому сайту, ну или просто чтоб на своем сайте ввел в поиск что-либо и при нажатии на "поиск" по введенному запросу отображалась информация в гугле (к примеру). Есть ли какие нибудь способы реализации такой идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно скопировать форму с другого сайта, поставить на свой сайт и подправить action.

```
<form action='http://google.ru/search' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='q'>
    <input type='submit' name='btnK'>
</form>
```

Comment: @atnartur,А не покажешь на примере гугла?

Comment: @jkwe45 подправил ответ. Пришлось через Dragonfly вытаскивать.

Comment: google предоставлят поисковую форму для твоего сайта и выводом результатов на твоем стайте, причем, если не ошибаюсь, поиск может вестись по твоему сайти или по интернету. Короче говоря, зачем кому-то дарить свой трафик - взял у гугля форму, сделал страницу для вывода результата и все пользователи остаются у тебя на сайте

Answer (score 1):

Для полноценного поиска на другом сайте требуется:

- Написать поискового робота
- Проиндексировать другой сайт
- Искать по результатам индексирования

Comment: А просто rss с другого сайта и в свою базу сунуть?:)

Comment: Не, мне нужен просто редирект